# Return all custom meta data for one custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, query-posts

I've set up a custom post type which has three custom meta fields: name, latitude, longitude. Each post already shows the name on an integrated map based on it's latitude and longitude.

I now would like to add a page to my site which shows ALL the names on a map based on their latitude and longitude.

I obviously know how to get single values out and get them on a map, but I'm not that experienced in Wordpress so I'm not sure what the best way would be to get all this information out in a structured way for what I'm trying to do. Any pointers to get me started would be appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If all of your custom post type posts have all meta fields that you need then you can use the `fields` argument and set it to `ids` which will work much faster for example:

```
//get your custom posts ids as an array
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'   => 'your_post_type',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'fields' => 'ids'
    )
);
//loop over each post
foreach($posts as $p){
    //get the meta you need form each post
    $long = get_post_meta($p,"longitude-key",true);
    $lati = get_post_meta($p,"latitude-key",true);
    $name = get_post_meta($p,"name-key",true);
    //do whatever you want with it
}
```

Comment: Bainternet, with some tweaks to your code I've been able to get at least all the information on my page. Still having some minor issues, but it looks like I'll be able to get this working now.

Comment: Glad i could help

Comment: Maybe a quick follow up question. Instead of `get_post_meta`, I used `$name = get_the_term_list($p, "name-key",true);` to get one of my values. This keeps however adding a "1" in front of the name. No idea where it comes from.

Comment: That's because `get_the_term_list` is used to get a term list of a taxonomy and not the meta of a post.

Comment: Yes, I needed a single term of a taxonomy. It returns the value, but also a "1" and it does so in every instance returned by the foreach loop.

Answer (score 9):

This code will give you all the posts with a longitude, latitude, and name assigned. Then you can loop through them to do your output and such.

```
$args = array(
    // basics
    'post_type'   => 'your_post_type',
    'post_status' => 'publish',

    // meta query
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => 'longitude-key',
            'value'   => '',
            'compare' => 'NOT'
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'latitude-key',
            'value'   => '',
            'compare' => 'NOT'
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'name-key',
            'value'   => '',
            'compare' => 'NOT'
        ),
    )
);
$posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Naturally you're gonna needa modify that, and I strongly recommend reading the [`WP_Query` documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to get that tuned exactly how you want, but that'll do it for you. If you use that on a template, the whole thing should be a piece of cake.

Comment: Thanks, when printing the returned array, that didn't exactly return what I was expecting. I guess I'll have to look in to that again.

Comment: That should give you an array of post objects in the set post type where `longitude-key`, `latitude-key`, and `name-key` are not blank. Does it not do this?

Comment: For now I took the `name-key` out and tested the code. I've printed the returned array, and copy pasted the result over to pastebin to let you see what it returns.
[http://pastebin.com/uhQHSths](http://pastebin.com/uhQHSths)

Comment: Looks like the query isn't executing, try declaring the `WP_Query` object separately then executing the `query()` method with `$args`.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use [get_metadata()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_metadata)?

If you pass the properly parameters you get all the meta attributes of a post (custom or not).

Example:

```
$META_ATTRIBUTES = get_metadata( 'post', get_the_ID(), '', true );
```

Note that I didn't use my cpt machine name as first parameter; **you have to use 'post'** or the function will return nothing.

Setting the third parameter (*meta key*) to an empty string you are telling to the function to retrieve all the meta attributes of the post.

Answer (score 0):

This is the  best way to get meta values in Custom post types include this code in **function.php** it include metaval array to response including all meta values

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'create_api_posts_meta_field' );

function create_api_posts_meta_field() {

 // register_rest_field ( 'name-of-post-type', 'name-of-field-to-return', array-of-callbacks-and-schema() )
 register_rest_field( 'tour', 'metaval', array(
 'get_callback' => 'get_post_meta_for_api',
 'schema' => null,
 )
 );
}

function get_post_meta_for_api( $object ) {
 //get the id of the post object array
 $post_id = $object['id'];

 //return the post meta
 return get_post_meta( $post_id );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we showing an example to relative displaying custom post type in WordPress and in this code have args in arrays and using wp_query with the loop for getting post data.

```
$args = array(  
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,  
    
    );

$loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 
    
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
    the_title(); 
the_excerpt();
endwhile;
```