# Get all properties of custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

Specifically, I'm trying to get get the 'Layout Group' of a given ThemeREX Custom Layout (which as I understand is just a Custom Post Type), but am also interested in seeing what other properties are available for that post.

I tried

```
print_r(get_post_meta(get_post(1738, 'ARRAY_A', 'display'),"",true));
```

but all that was returned  was the number 1.

I'm guessing the meta is not what I'm looking for. Is there a way to iterate through all the custom properties that are registered with that post's CPT?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return all custom meta data for one custom post type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45199/return-all-custom-meta-data-for-one-custom-post-type)

Comment: (You want Marco's answer from the above question, not the accepted answer)

Answer (score 1):

To get **all** the `post_meta` for a post, use:

```
$postmeta = get_post_meta(1738);
print_r($postmeta);
```

...which will give you a nested array of values that you can explore.

Once you've worked out what you need, you can get the individual setting / property / meta with:

```
$mySetting = get_post_meta(1738, "my-post-meta-key", true);
```

Take a look at the [relevant entry on the WordPress Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) for a bit more detail.

Comment: I still get just the number 1 returned. I tried it with a few different custom post types as well as a standard page... same results.

Comment: What did your `print_r()` result in? Have you checked the database to make sure the value is not "1"?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
print_r( get_post_type_object( ( get_post( 1738 ) )->post_type ) );
```

It should print an object of class [`WP_Post_Type`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_post_type/).

Comment: From context I believe they’re asking about post _meta_, not post type arguments, which wouldn’t include anything like what they describe.